# How to save the dynmaically created checkboxes selected values in DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have a matrix of checkboxes created dynamically from the two database tables(tblPrivileges,tblViews) as shown in image:

[image: Array of checkboxes]

Vertical records are from tblPrivileges and horizontal 3 records are from tblViews. Here is the code for the above matrix:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        int rowCnt;
        int rowCtr;

        rowCnt = 1;
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString;
        SqlDataAdapter adp1 = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tblViews", con);
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        adp1.Fill(ds1);
        DataTable g = new DataTable();
        adp1.Fill(g);


        for (rowCtr = 1; rowCtr <= rowCnt; rowCtr++)
        {
            TableRow tRow = new TableRow();
            privilegeTable.Rows.Add(tRow);
            foreach (DataRow checkboxTitle in g.Rows)
            {
                TableCell tc = new TableCell();
                //System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox cb = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox();


                tc.Text = checkboxTitle.ItemArray[1].ToString();
                TableCell tCell = new TableCell();
                tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
                tCell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(checkboxTitle.ItemArray[1].ToString()));

            }
        }
        CheckBoxList chklist = new CheckBoxList();
        //SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select v.View_ID,v.View_Name,p.Privilege_ID,p.Privilege_Name from tblViews as v right outer join tblPrivileges p on v.View_ID = p.Privilege_ID", con);
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tblPrivileges", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adp.Fill(dt);

        foreach (DataRow name in dt.Rows)
        {

            TableRow tr = new TableRow();
            TableCell tcTitle = new TableCell();

            tcTitle.Text = name.ItemArray[1].ToString();
            tr.Cells.Add(tcTitle);

            foreach (DataRow checkboxTitle in g.Rows)
            {
                TableCell tc = new TableCell();
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox cb = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox();

                tc.Text = checkboxTitle.ItemArray[1].ToString();

                tc.Controls.Add(cb);
                tr.Cells.Add(tc);


            }

            privilegeTable.Rows.Add(tr);
            base.OnInit(e);
        }

    }
```

I need to select the checkbox values and after click of a button, the selected checkbox values should go to the common table. Also I am not able to set attribute "ID" of the checkboxes. How to save the selected checkbox values on a button click in the DB table?

Kindly help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the [asp.net page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms178472.aspx) in order to dynamically add server controls to pages.  You are adding the controls to the page too late.

Comment: I am adding the checkboxes on PreInit event? I will try out the options but how to get the values of selected checkboxes?